# Sorting in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have written a small code in MeteorJS which uses Mongodb and Iron:router (I am new to MeteorJS). Everything worked fine initially and towards the end of it, sorting stopped working. To explain a little more, the list of websites must be sorted according to the upvotes it has received and date of creation. Here are the relevant sections of the code:

```
//Sorting websites based on userfilter or votes
websites:function(){
  if (Session.get("userFilter")){
    return Websites.find({ createdBy: Session.get("userFilter") }, { sort: { createdOn: -1, up: -1 }});
  } else {
    return Websites.find({},{ sort: { createdOn: -1, up: -1 }});
  } 
},
```

```
{{#each websites}}
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="{{url}}" class="site_name">{{title}}</a>
      <p class="site_desc">{{description}}</p>
      <br>
      <p class="upvote_button">Upvote: {{up}}</p>
      <p class="downvote_button">Downvote: {{down}}</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-upvote" id="upvote_button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-downvote" id="downvote_button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      <br>
      <p class="added-by">Added By: 
        <a href="#" class="js-filter">{{getUser createdBy}}</a>
      </p>
      <p>Added On: {{createdOn}}</p>
      <a href="/single_website/{{_id}}">Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify sorting according to more than one property, Mongo will sort first by the first property, then for documents that fall at the same "position", it will use your second property to order those, etc.

So you will get documents (websites) sorted by `createdOn` date first, and for those which have the exactly same date (including time if present), by `up` value. I guess this is not what you would like.

Furthermore, since you use a dictionary / mapping object type to specify your sort, you will depend on the JS engine ordering implementation. In most cases, it will order your properties by insertion order, i.e. 1) `createdOn` 2) `up` in your case.

http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#sortspecifiers

> The [`{a: 1, b: -1}`] form will only work if your JavaScript implementation preserves the order of keys in objects. Most do, most of the time, but it’s up to you to be sure.

In the end, you might have looked for this sorting:

```js
Websites.find({}, {
  sort: [
    ["up", "desc"], // Sort first by "up" value
    ["createdOn", "desc"] // then for websites with same up value, order by date
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want ot do something like this

```
Websites.find({}).sort({createdOn:-1, up:-1})
```

Hope it works

if not try adding this

```
Websites.ensureIndex({createdOn: -1, up: -1})
```

Thanks